# redux tutorial: const store in this.props

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm doing the tutorial react, video #24

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-passing-the-store-down-explicitly-via-props

Map of components:

TodoApp ->  VisibleTodoList -> FilterLink

I just need to know why this code in VisibleTodoList and FilterLink component  : "const { store } = this.props", it's this  getting the first element in this.props? to see at the bottom my console log for this.props and store object for every of these components.

```
class VisibleTodoList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
      this.forceUpdate()
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const { store } = props;

    const state = store.getState();

    return (
      <TodoList
        todos={
          getVisibleTodos(
            state.todos,
            state.visibilityFilter
          )
        }
        onTodoClick={id =>
          store.dispatch({
            type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
            id
          })
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

class FilterLink extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
      this.forceUpdate()
    );
  }
  .
  . // Rest of component as before down to `render()`
  .
  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const { store } = props
    const state = store.getState()
    .
    . // Rest of component as before
    .
  }
}

const TodoApp = ({ store }) => (
  <div>
    <AddTodo store={store} />
    <VisibleTodoList store={store} />
    <Footer store={store} />
  </div>
);

const render = () => {

  ReactDOM.render(
    <TodoApp store={createStore(todoApp)} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

store.subscribe(render);
```

FilterLink

When I print this.props for VisibleTodoList Component on the console i have two elements: store and *proto* , this is clear.

```
Object {store: Object}
store : Object
    dispatch :
    dispatch(action) getState: getState()
    replaceReducer : replaceReducer(nextReducer)
    subscribe : subscribe(listener)
    Symbol(observable) : observable()
    __proto__ : Object
__proto__ : Object
```

but when I print this.props for FilterLink Component on the console i have:
(I dont understand this order, store objet it's the first element ?)

```
Object {filter: "SHOW_ALL", store: Object, children: "All"}
    children :    "All"
    filter :  "SHOW_ALL"
store : Object
__proto__   : Object
```

When I print on the console 'store'  for FilterLink Component, i get:

```
Object {}
dispatch    :    dispatch(action)
getState  :   getState()
replaceReducer   :     replaceReducer(nextReducer)
subscribe   :    subscribe(listener)
Symbol(observable)   : observable()
__proto__   :
Object
```

I need to know more about "const { store } = this.props", it's not clear for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const { store } = this.props` is using ES6 [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Assigning a constant like to the object on the right side pull out the value for the key that has the same name as the variable (in this case `store` and assigns it to the store variable. It's the equivalent of

```
const store = this.props.store
```