# Best way to clone a React component (on demand)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, clone

I would like to clone a react component (on demand - triggered by a button click). The clone should have the same properties as the original component, but not depend on it. Below is an example of my child component. I would like to clone the parent component (containing a number of child components).

The cloned component should have the same behaviour and the children should, initially, have the same values as the original.

What is the best (recommended) way to clone a component?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class MySelector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.makeApiCall = this.makeApiCall.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      data : [],
      hasData : false,
      errorMsg : null
    };

    this.errorMsg = props.errorMsg;
    this.name = props.name || '';
    this.label = props.label;
    this.apiPath = props.apiPath;
    this.keyName = props.keyName;
    this.valueName = props.valueName;
    this.changeFunction = props.changeFunction;
  }

  handleChange(e){
    const newValue = e.target.value.trim();
    const newText = e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].text.trim();
    const error = this.changeFunction(this.name, newValue, newText);
    this.setState( () => ( { errorMsg : error } ));
  }

  makeApiCall(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    fetch(`${this.apiPath}`, {headers: headers})
      .then(res => res.json() )
      .then(data => {
        const onlyOneOption = (data.value.length==1);
        const selectData = (onlyOneOption) ? data.value : [{name:'Select an option', genericKey:1337}].concat(data.value);
        if(onlyOneOption){
          this.changeFunction(this.name, selectData[0][this.valueName], selectData[0][this.keyName]);
        }
        this.setState({data:selectData, hasData:true});
      }); 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeApiCall();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="option">
        {(this.label) && 
            <div className="option__text">
              <h3>{this.label}</h3>
            </div>
        }
        <div>
          {(!this.state.hasData && this.isAccessible) && <p>Loading...</p>}
          {(!this.isAccessible) && <select ref={this.name} className="add-option__input"><option key="dummy">...</option></select>}
          <select 
            ref={this.name} 
            defaultValue="null" 
            name={this.name} 
            id={this.name} required
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="add-option__input"
            style={(this.state.hasData) ? {display:'inline'} : {display:'none'}}
          >
            {(this.state.hasData) && 
              this.state.data.map( ds => <option key={ds[this.keyName]?ds[this.keyName]:ds.genericKey} value={ds[this.keyName]}>{ds[this.valueName]}</option>)
            }
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
MySelector.defaultProps = {
  errorMsg: '',
  name: 'default', 
  label: 'Default',
  apiPath: '/rest/api/uri', 
  keyName: 'key',
  valueName: 'value'
};
MySelector.propTypes = {
  errorMsg: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  apiPath: PropTypes.string,
  keyName: PropTypes.string,
  valueName: PropTypes.string,
  changeFunction: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Comment: Sounds like `React.cloneElement` might be useful. Possibly hold an array of them in `this.state`?

Comment: just FYI did You know that You can have props like this const {errorMsg, name, apiPath, valueName} = this.props;  ?

Comment: @MichalCholewiński - Thanks, did not think of using destructuring there, it cleans up the code nicely! 

More on the subject in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668122/redux-tutorial-const-store-in-this-props

Comment: @Andrew - Thank you! I will give it a try.